Look up but for columns not rows
I want to fill the price column in sheet 1 based on two criteria
first criteria is a code which i will use xlookup to find the respective row in the table in sheet 2
the second criteria is the one in questions the second creiteria is a date and its reflected in  the table in sheet 2 as columns each month is column so the result is a matrix of prices, how to make the formula go column by column untill it gets the correct month.


i tried searching index and match but couldn't understand how to use them

Welcome to the board! Try adding a desired result as well, preferaply using TableMarkdown (and your input aswell); it's easier for us to copy the data and run tests on it.

Also 1235 01-03-24 doesn't match with anything as sheet 2 only goes up to February.

Based on Example 5 from Microsoft documentation, you can use a nested Xlookup:
=XLOOKUP(EOMONTH(B2,-1)+1,Sheet2!$B$1:$D$1,
XLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$3,Sheet2!$B$2:$D$3))


where Sheet2 contains


thank you very much i didnt know i can use xlookup for columns in that way, it worked for the data set that i have

I'm assuming you're date is formatted as MM/DD/YY; and your dates in sheet 2 are just the 12 months;
=XLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!$A3$:$A$50,CHOOSECOLS(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$50,XMATCH(MONTH(B3);MONTH(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$12))),"")
Some clarification:
A3 is the first cell with a 'code' (1234) in it;
Sheet2!$A3$:$A$50 is the list of codes in sheet2;
CHOOSECOLS(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$50,XMATCH(MONTH(B3);MONTH(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$12))) chooses a row in the set of prices, each row is the number of a month (jan=1, feb=2, ...), unless they're not in order, or you have multiple years, this will break (I'll try and get a workaround for that), returns the given price for that code and month combination.
XMATCH(MONTH(B3);MONTH(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$12)) basically searches for the right row by comparing the month of the first date, with the month of the second.
Does it for me.
EDIT:
=XLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!$A3$:$A$50,CHOOSECOLS(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$50,XMATCH(B3-DAY(B3)+1;Sheet2!$B$1:$B$12)),"")
Dropped the first month part and changed it with B3-DAY(B3)+1, which results in the actual first day of the month, and dropped the MONTH() in the second part, now it should work for all years, even if your dates are unsorted in sheet2.
Here's what it looks like to me:


You can use Index Match, there will be multiple tutorials for this (one example).
For your use case, you want to match the row of the lookup table using the "code" value,  and match the column using the "date" value :
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$C$3,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,0),MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$A$1:$C$1,0))


thank you it worked but i had to add -1 in the date criteria because it always returned the next column that reflected the date i want  INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$C$3,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,0),MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$A$1:$C$1,0)-1)
